# Django Rest Framework nested relationship performance on SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have been looking for an answer but get none. This is the situation:
I have 3 models defined like this:

```py
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=False)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='cities', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Home(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='homes', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

The response that the people needs on homes is something like this

```json
[
    {
        "code": "10011",
        "city": "Municipio 1",
        "state": "Departamento 1"
    },
    {
        "code": "10012",
        "city": "Municipio 1",
        "state": "Departamento 1"
    }
]
```

I was able to create that response doing this with the serializer:

```py
class HomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=City.objects.all())
    state = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Home
        fields = ['code', 'city', 'state']

    def get_state(self, obj):
        return obj.city.state.nombre
```

But Im not sure if this is the right way to do it, `home` is a table that is gonna grow up a lot (maybe 1M+ rows), and I am thinking that this solution is gonna hit the database multiple times. Now I know that I can add filtering and pagination, but I am concern about the performance of this solution. I also tried with `depth = 2` but they hated it.

I've been searching on the docs and the examples (that are really good) just take 1 nested relationship, so Im really lost here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you generate the queryset that is passed to the serializer you should use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the related data in a single query. This way when you access the related fields a DB query will not be performed because the data is already there

```
class HomeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Home.objects.select_related('city__state')
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer
```

Comment: Thank you @Iain, yeah as im new to django I checked `select_related` after I post the question, but I have the same doubt. How good is your solution if the table grow up a lot?